# AngularJS 1.4.3 ngRepeat prints {{ variableName }} instead of value when used in directive with isolate scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

After we upgraded our project's AngularJS from 1.2.28 to 1.4.3 the ngRepeat inside an isolated scope stopped evaluate variables. It started printing "{{variableName}}" instead of the value.

**Edit:** the problem was caused by a patch for iOS8 Webkit bug: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9128

The issue comes from the wrapping HTML element around the ngRepeat. If I remove it, it works fine. If I remove the isolated scope it works too.

And the most strangest thing is that I tried the same approach on CODE PEN and it works pretty fine but not on our project.
Here is the codepen code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXgYjN

Here is the controller:

```
app.controller('CustomersController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.customers = [
    {
        name: 'David',
        street: '1234 Anywhere St.'
    },
    {
        name: 'Tina',
        street: '1800 Crest St.'
    },
    {
        name: 'Michelle',
        street: '890 Main St.--'
    }
  ];
}]);
```

And the directive:

```
app.directive('myIsolatedScope', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      customers: '='
    },
    template: 
      '<p>' + 
      '<span ng-repeat="(key, customer) in customers" class="{{customer.name}}">Name: {{customer.name}}| Street: {{customer.street}}<br /></span>' +
      '</p>',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {},
    compile: function() {},
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {}
  };
});
```

The HTML:

```
<body ng-app="directivesModule" ng-controller="CustomersController">
 <h3>Custom Directive</h3>
 <my-isolated-scope customers="customers"></my-isolated-scope>
</body>
```

Comment: if it works on code pen but not on your project, it means that your app has to be crashing somewhere else, and that prevents the directive from executing properly (which explain why the values does not get replaced). What errors do you have in the javascript console?

Comment: @Eloims, no errors at all in the browser's console. I hope somebody have had such problem and can give me some directions where to search for the problem's source.

Comment: If the codepen does not reproduce the error, we need more details. What html element do you wrap it into? Some default html elements are transformed into their directive equivalents in angular, which can mess with your scope hierarchy.

Comment: And also try to clean up the cache in the browser, redeploy your files if you have backend. And try to using different browsers to see if same thing  happen.

Comment: @Eloims, the issue is that the parent HTML element takes the isolated scope.
I tested with other ng directives that create an isolated scope and the issue still appears.
This doesn't work too: `template: '<p><span ng-if="customers">{{customers}}</span></p>'`.
It seems to stop evaluating the variables inside the children elements of the template.

Comment: @krzysztof-safjanowski, the title is misleading now. The problem is not in IE8 at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem was only on our project I started digging and found the root of it. It was because of this patch: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9128

Answer (score 0):

I had tried your sample in Angular JS 1.4.x version, it works fine for me. Refer the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/B6F0DIhIRil70lwEYBZH?p=preview) Link.

Code Sample as well:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>View</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('directivesModule' ,[]);
app.controller('CustomersController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.customers = [
    {
        name: 'David',
        street: '1234 Anywhere St.'
    },
    {
        name: 'Tina',
        street: '1800 Crest St.'
    },
    {
        name: 'Michelle',
        street: '890 Main St.--'
    }
  ];
}]);

app.directive('myIsolatedScope', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
    scope: {
      customers: '='
    },
    template: '<p>' + 
      '<span ng-repeat="(key, customer) in customers" class="{{customer.name}}">Name: {{customer.name}}| Street: {{customer.street}}<br /></span>' +
    '</p>',
  controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

  },

  compile: function() {

  },

  link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

  }
};
});
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="directivesModule" ng-controller="CustomersController">
 <h3>Custom Directive</h3>
 <my-isolated-scope customers="customers"></my-isolated-scope>
</body>
</html>
```

Just for your information:
AngularJs has stopped support for IE 8 from Version 1.3.
Refer [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) link.
Better Stop supporting IE 8 for project or Product instead of spending time to find alternative solution.

Comment: yes I miss understood your statement. Now i had tried using plunker, it works fine for me. Please check the post.

Comment: Thank you @sathish
The issue happens in Chrome and Firefox. I am not talking about IE8 at all. Sorry for the wrong explanation and misleading you.

Comment: Still it works fine for me, Did you tried my plunker url in chrome or firefox?

Comment: it works for me too. There is something on our project that breaks it.
Any idea what could prevent ng directives (ngRepeat, ngIf ...) from evaluating code if they are used inside isolated scope?